# mssql query can't find string which contains characters č and ć

Tags: sql-server

I use MSSQL server 2012 express edition.
When I execute query to get all from table, everything is alright, but when I filter it with "where" clause, I can't get records which contains characters č or ć.
What can I do ?

--next query works fine

```
select * from poslovneJedinice
```

--in next queries i get problems

```
select * from poslovneJedinice where Naziv = 'Gračanica'

select * from poslovneJedinice where Naziv = 'Gradačac'

select * from poslovneJedinice where Naziv = 'BućaPotok'
```

Comment: What are the collation settings for the table/column? What is the datatype of the Naziv column?

Comment: If your column data type is `nvarchar`, prefix the literal string with `N` to denote Unicode: `where Naziv = N'Gračanica'`.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below SQL Queries

Please find [COLLATE_NAME] from [here](https://database.guide/how-to-find-the-collation-in-sql-server-t-sql/)

```
select * from poslovneJedinice where Naziv = 'Gračanica' COLLATE [COLLATE_NAME]

select * from poslovneJedinice where Naziv = 'Gradačac' COLLATE [COLLATE_NAME]

select * from poslovneJedinice where Naziv = 'BućaPotok' COLLATE [COLLATE_NAME]
```